# R summary statistics from dataframe by group

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

I apologize if this is a repeat, I really don't know the proper terminology for what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a dataframe of drug lab results as follows:

```
╔══════╦════════╗
║ drug ║ result ║
╠══════╬════════╣
║ A    ║     10 ║
║ B    ║    150 ║
║ B    ║     50 ║
║ A    ║     14 ║
║ C    ║      3 ║
║ C    ║      7 ║
╚══════╩════════╝
```

For each drug, I'm using dplyr to remove outliers (>4 SD's from the mean) using the following:

```
cleaned <- data %>% group_by(drug) %>% filter(abs(result-mean(result))/sd(result) < 4)
```

But now I would like to know how many outliers I'm removing per drug, so essentially I want to generate a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ drug ║ total (N) ║ outliers ║ % outliers ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ A    ║       100 ║        7 ║ 0.07       ║
║ B    ║       200 ║       45 ║ 0.225      ║
║ C    ║       300 ║       99 ║ 0.33       ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no sample data, I decided to use the mtcars data set for demonstration. If I follow your approach, the following would be one way. Here, you want to find out the part of data you filtered out; you use `setdiff()` to collect the data. Since `am` is the group variable in this demonstration, use `count()` and find how many outliers exist for each group (i.e., either 0 or 1 for `am`). You further try to get a vector you need using select and unlist. Then, you use `summarise()` and count how many data points exist for `am` and add new columns using `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
group_by(am) %>%
filter(abs(disp-mean(disp))/sd(disp) < 1) %>%
setdiff(mtcars, .) %>%
count(am) %>%
select(2) %>%
unlist-> out

#out
#n1 n2 
#8  2 

summarize(group_by(mtcars, am), total = n()) %>%
mutate(outliers = out, percent = outliers / total)

#     am total outliers   percent
#  (dbl) (int)    (int)     (dbl)
#1     0    19        8 0.4210526
#2     1    13        2 0.1538462
```

Taking devmacrile's advice, I did the following. First, you group the data with a group variable. Then, you want to set up a flag column. Here, I created the column with `mutate()`. You have TRUE and FALSE in the column. You count how many data points exist by `am` and `check` in `count()`. You then reshape the outcome with `spread()` in the `tidyr` package. Now you calculate total data point for the 0 group and 1 group in `am`. Once again, you group the data with `am`, and finally you handle the percentage calculation and column renaming in `transmute()`. I hope this sample will help you.

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(am) %>%
mutate(check = abs(disp-mean(disp))/sd(disp) < 1)  %>%
count(am, check) %>%
spread(check, n) %>%
mutate(total = `FALSE` + `TRUE`) %>%
group_by(am) %>%
transmute(total, outliers = `FALSE`, percentage = `FALSE` / total)

#     am total outliers percentage
#  (dbl) (int)    (int)      (dbl)
#1     0    19        8  0.4210526
#2     1    13        2  0.1538462
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going right to filter(), I would create a flag field (i.e. 1 or 0) indicating whether or not the result was an outlier, and then pipe that into the appropriate summarization.

Comment: I just figured out how to use summarize.  I've only been using R for about a week so if there is a better way let me know:


`isnorm <- function(x) { sum(abs(x-mean(x))/sd(x) < 4) }`


`summarize(data %>% group_by(drug), N=n(), normal=isnorm(test), outliers=N-normal, out_pct=outliers/N)`

Comment: @AlexanderDavid Yeah, that looks right. More idiomatic is to chain the whole thing, like `data %>% group_by(drug) %>% summarise(...)`